# How to fill a HashMap from another HashMap using streams

Tags: java, collections, hashmap, java-stream

I am trying to create a new Hashmap<Integer, Map<String, Product>> from a filled HashMap<String,Product> applying Java Streams and I am receiving all time **java.util.HashMap$Node cannot be cast to class java.util.Map** and I am not able to see the what is wrong.

There is probably a simpler and more logical way to do it but this is what I came up with

```
Map<String, Product> hashMapChild = new HashMap<>();

hashMapChild.put("PC000123", new Product("reference1", "product1", price1));
hashMapChild.put("PC000234", new Product("reference2", "product2", price2));


Map<Integer, Map<String, Product>> hashMapParent = hashMapChild.entrySet()
                .stream()
                .collect(HashMap<Integer, Map<String, Product>>::new,
                         (map, streamValue) -> map.put((int) Math.floor(Math.random()*100),(Map<String, Product>) streamValue),
                                    
                         (map, map2) -> {
                             System.out.println(map);
                             System.out.println(map2);
                         });
        
        hashMapParent.forEach((k, v) -> System.out.println(k + ":" + v));
```

On the other hand. How would be possible to get an auto increment index instead of a random value?

Many thanks in advance

The output could be something like that:

```
<1, <COMPGAM012, Product{reference='COMPGAM012', name='laptop', prize=750.56}>>
<2, <PC000124, Product{reference='PC000124', name='Desktop', prize=400.56}>>
```

Comment: What is your new hash map supposed to look like? What are the keys? What are the values? What should each key/value pair from the original map be mapped to in the new map?

Comment: Can you give use the output example? With data you have in `hashMapChild`?

Comment: For index you can use this `AtomicInteger index = new AtomicInteger(0);`. Declare it before that `stream` and replace `(int) Math.floor(Math.random()*100)` with `index.getAndIncrement()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I understand is, you want to assign an index to every entry from your Map.
So, the result you want is not `Map<Integer, Map<String, Product>>`. Actually you want `Map<Integer, Map.Entry<String, Product>>`.

And for index you can use `AtomicInteger`.

```
AtomicInteger index = new AtomicInteger(1);

Map<Integer, Map.Entry<String, Product>> hashMapParent = hashMapChild.entrySet()
                .stream()
                .collect(HashMap<Integer, Map.Entry<String, Product>>::new,
                        (map, streamValue) -> map.put(index.getAndIncrement(), streamValue),

                        (map, map2) -> {
                            System.out.println(map);
                            System.out.println(map2);
                        });
```

Simplified version:

```
Map<Integer, Map.Entry<String, String>> hashMapParent = hashMapChild.entrySet()
                .stream()
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                        k -> index.getAndIncrement(),
                        v -> v
                ));
```

Comment: Many thanks. It works. The problem have been don't declare with Map.Entry

Answer (score 0):

As per the code you have provided, hashMapChild contains 2 data and as per the structure defined for hashMapParent it should have the entire hashMapChild as value for hashMapParent. Eg:

```
Map<String, Product> hashMapChild = new HashMap<>();
hashMapChild.put("PC000123", new Product("reference1", "product1", price1));
hashMapChild.put("PC000234", new Product("reference2", "product2", price2));

Map<Integer, Map<String, Product>> hashMapParent = new HashMap<>();
hashMapParent.put(0, hashMapChild);
```

From the code looks like you will have only one `hashMapChild` which will contain all the products, so I don't think so you need to have any kind of iteration in this case.

Or should I consider that you would like to add more maps like this `Map<String, Product> hashMapChild = new HashMap<>();` and adding them in `hashMapParent` like:

```
hashMapParent.put(0, hashMapChild);
hashMapParent.put(1, hashMapChild1);
hashMapParent.put(2, hashMapChild2);
```

Comment: Many thanks for your response, but the idea is not create a one Parent with the whole hashMap child. 
My idea is create as new hashMapParent with so many entries like the hashMapChild size. For this reason I thought in use streams. Because for each hashMapChild I want to create  a new entry. 

HashMapParent and HashMapChild should have the same size at the end

Comment: ok but what’s the use case for this, when you already have a map with keys why do you wanna create another one.